# Rstatix anova_test doesn't recognize "correction" argument

Tags: anova, two-way, rstatix

Without the argument, it seems to work.

```
>anova_test(data=Plantaris_Morpho_and_WB,dv=Plantaris_body,wid="Mouse_#",between=Day,within=Treatment)
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

         Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1           Day   3  28  7.020 1.00e-03     * 0.290
2     Treatment   1  28 33.260 3.43e-06     * 0.352
3 Day:Treatment   3  28  0.674 5.75e-01       0.032
```

With it, I get this.

```
>anova_test(data=Plantaris_Morpho_and_WB,dv=Plantaris_body,wid="Mouse_#",between=Day,within=Treatment,correction="auto")
Error in anova_test(data = Plantaris_Morpho_and_WB, dv = Plantaris_body,  : 
  unused argument (correction = "auto")
```

What's going on?